# Failed to use Code Prettify plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am a newbie in WordPress.

I am trying to insert a code block in Sparkling Theme of Wordpress.
This is my code in editor:

```
Following is a snippet of a sample Layout file.
<pre class="prettyprint">
<code class="xml">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="This will print hello world" />

   <!-- More GUI components go here  -->

</LinearLayout>
</code></pre>
```

And I am getting this as output:
[image: Output of above code]

Please tell me where i am doing wrong. Thanks in Advance..:)

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is xml tag symbol.

Change < to  `&lt;`

Change > to `&gt;`

This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean insert code block in WP Editor or in theme php file?

However, you need to convert your code to html entities first. for exmaple:

## In PHP

```
<?php
$code = '<xml>...</xml>';

echo '<pre><code>';
echo htmlentities($code);
echo '</code></pre>';
?>
```

## In WP Editor

Paste your code via **Visual** mode, then the wp will auto convert it to html entities in **Text** mode.

Comment: I am doing it in WP editor but do i really need to add a php script?

Comment: No, if you just want to insert code to wp editor, you don't need to touch any php.